# Get Javascript maxLength in input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with downloading and displaying the value, when set to "rigidly" maxLenght - everything works fine, but when I want the script to download the value myself, I have a problem.

The script is supposed to get the value maxlenght = "" from each `<input>` and after typing by the user it will print out how many characters are left.

```
var maxLen = document.getElementsByClassName("handlerWorld").maxLength;

function countChar(jqObj) {
    var len = jqObj.val().length;
    var diff = maxLen - len;

    if (len > maxLen) {
        len = maxLen;
        diff = 0;
    }
    jqObj.val(jqObj.val().substr(0, len)).prev('label').find('span.chars-twenty').text(diff);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[class*='handlerWorld']").keyup(function () {
        countChar($(this));
    }).each(function () {
        countChar($(this));
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="nameIput">Nazwa firmy <span>Remaining: <span class="chars-twenty"></span></label>
          <input type="text" id="name" maxlength="140" name="name" class="form-control handlerWorld">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="urlInput">URL <span>Remaining: <span class="chars-twenty"></span></label>
          <input type="text" id="url" name="url" maxlength="100" class="form-control handlerWorld">
          
        </div>
```

Edit:

Now I would like it to show the number of characters, e.g .:

10/140

quantity written / quantity in the value "maxlenght"

```
$("#add-category").find('span.maxchar').text(maxLen);
```

They work but not as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the MaxLength calculation to the Count method

```
var maxLen = jqObj.attr("maxlength");
```

here's fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/d53yjpr8/1/

```js
function countChar(jqObj) {
  var maxLen = jqObj.attr("maxlength");
  var len = jqObj.val().length;
  var diff = maxLen - len;

  if (len > maxLen) {
    len = maxLen;
    diff = 0;
  }
  jqObj.val(jqObj.val().substr(0, len)).prev('label').find('span.chars-twenty').text(diff);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class*='handlerWorld']").keyup(function() {
    countChar($(this));
  }).each(function() {
    countChar($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nameIput">Test <span>Remaining:</span> <span class="chars-twenty"></span></label>
  <input type="text" id="name" maxlength="140" name="name" class="form-control handlerWorld">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="urlInput">URL <span>Remaining:</span> <span class="chars-twenty"></span></label>
  <input type="text" id="url" name="url" maxlength="100" class="form-control handlerWorld">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's work. And if I wanted to make a module more - I edited the post.